# How to find antilog for a number using java programm?

Tags: java, logarithm

can someone please tell me How to find antilog for a number using java program? i am new to this java
`Math.log(10)` gives the log value. now I want to take this output and verify using antilog that program is giving right value.please help me.

Comment: think about this mathematically

Comment: http://www.shodor.org/unchem/math/logs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mathematically: e^(ln x) = x

in java:

```
Math.pow(Math.E, (Math.log(x)) == x; //equals true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Logarithm class in Java to calculate log and antilog. More on this is provided [here](http://www.jsc.nildram.co.uk/api/jsc/util/Logarithm.html).